# problem updating ubuntu 20.04.1 on Raspberry Pi 4 -- error refers to apt-secure (8) manpage

Tags: updates

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease
Ign:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports eoan InRelease
Hit:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates InRelease
Ign:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports eoan-updates InRelease
Hit:6 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports InRelease
Hit:7 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security InRelease
Ign:8 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports eoan-security InRelease
Err:9 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports eoan Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.xxx.xx.152 80]
Err:10 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports eoan-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.xxx.xx.152 80]
Err:11 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports eoan-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.xxx.xx.152 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports eoan Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports eoan-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports eoan-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: Why do you have mixed 'eoan' and 'focal' sources? A system in good condition should have only one release listed. Your errors are perfectly normal and expected for 'eoan' sources, since that release is past End Of Life, and there are no more updates for it. How you fix the problem depends upon your answer to "*Why do you have mixed 'eoan' and 'focal' sources?*"

Comment: Hi, good question but one I cannot answer.  I don't have the knowledge regarding why two releases.  I'm using a Raspberry pi4, with port forwarding on my router. If you have any ideas, that would be very helpful.  Thank you kindly

Comment: Whatever method was used to upgrade from 19.10 to 20.04 was either done improperly or suffered some terrible error. This leads me to distrust the stability of your system. Advice: 1) Delete your 'eoan' sources from /etc/apt/sources.list, then 2) Run `sudo apt update`. If this causes additional serious problems, be prepared to back up your data and reinstall.

Comment: Thanks again for your help.  I tried several things then broke it.  Yes, it was most likely a bad update from 19 to 20.  Lessons learned